# How to read if a checkbox is checked in typescript?

Tags: html, typescript, checkbox, angular-material, checked

This must be something basic which I can't figure out how to do it. I want to display in console if a check box is checked. My html and typescript code are:

```
  <div class="my-form-field" style="display: block;margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <mat-checkbox id="is3dCheckBox" (ngModel)="handleInputChange()">Split tag in bits</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
```

And .ts file has the function `handleInputChange()`

```
handleInputChange() {
    var element = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("is3dCheckBox");
    var isChecked = element.checked;
    if (isChecked == true)
        console.log("Checked");
    if (isChecked == false)
        console.log("Not Checked");
}
```

My console has no error, but it's not displaying the text when checkbox is checked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ng model is not for binding if it changes

Comment: I have tried alsongModelChange, but with no success.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use a type assertion to tell TypeScript it is an HTMLInputElement: var element =  document. getElementById("is3dCheckBox"); var isChecked = element.

Answer (score -1):

You can bind to the `change` event of `mat-checkbox`.

*Template*

```html
<mat-checkbox (change)="onChange($event.checked)"></mat-checkbox>
```

*Component Class*

```js
onChange(checked) {
  console.log(checked);
}
```

Also just as a side note, in Angular you should generally not feel the need to directly reference the `document` object to access DOM elements. For this Angular has [ElementRef](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/element-refs-in-angular-templates).